# Render Observable in Angular 5

Tags: angular, async-await, angular-ng-if, angular-observable

I'm trying to render an **Observable** in Angular. I'm making a request to an API to get some data but, when I try render it, nothing appears at the browser.

This is the **service** I'm using to get the data about 1 user:

```
export class UserService {

  public _url: string = "https://url/rest/user/";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUser(id): Observable<IUser>{
    return this.http.get<IUser>(this._url + id)
                  .catch(this.errorHandler);
  }

  errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse){
    return Observable.throw(error.message);
  }
}
```

This is the user **component**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  providers: [ UserService ],
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})

export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  public userId;    
  public errorMsg;
  user: IUser;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private _userService: 
  UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    let id = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    this.userId = id;

    this._userService.getUser(this.userId)
          .subscribe(data => this.user = data,
                 error => this.errorMsg = error);

  }

}
```

And the view **HTML** I'm using to render de User is:

```
<div>
  <h2>{{user?.firstName}} {{user?.lastName}}</h2>
    <dl>
     <dt>Age:</dt>
     <dd>{{user?.age}}</dd>

     <dt>ID:</dt>
     <dd>{{user?.id}}</dd>

     <dt>Email:</dt>
     <dd>{{user?.email}}</dd>
   </dl>
</div>
```

In this example I have no errors but the user fields are all empty, nothing is showed. I've tried to use this:

```
<div *ngIf="user | async; let user; else loading">
<ng-template #loading>Loading User Data...</ng-template>
```

But it doesnt works, The console shows:

```
Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' ...
```

I'm doing the same procress in another component where I use an array of Users like IUser[], this time I'm showing the data with an ngfor and everything is correct, the data appears at the browser as expected.. I'm doing it the same way I've explained above but using ngif or user?.id and without arrays.

Comment: what do you get if you add a console.log(data) in your subscribe method? Or better, if you set a breakpoint there

Comment: Hi, I had already checked the data with a console.log, and the data its correct, I receive the content I want to show. And inside the subcribe method, the data is also correctly asigned to my user.

Comment: Could you maybe post a minimal version of your problem on stackblitz? https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Sure, here it is, I think..   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rw6tvf

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API returns a list of users, not a single user (even though you indicated the response to be a `IUser`)

You need to do some mapping to only take the first element:

```
getUser(id): Observable<IUser> {

    return this.http.get<IUser>(this._url + id).map(resp => resp[0])
                    .catch(this.errorHandler);
}
```

See modified code: https://angular-uqsks5.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 2):

As for the final error, the `async` pipe only works with observables. So instead of saving the data in the user variable and then passing that to the async pipe, try saving the observable itself: `const user$ = this._userService.getUser(this.userId)` and then passing that into the `async` pipe: `{{ user$ | async }}`.

You can then access the properties like this: `{{ (user$ | async).age }}` and so on.

For your initial error, it may just be an issue with the request. You could try logging out the value of `data` to the console in your subscription to troubleshoot. Perhaps you need `data.response` or something. (One way you could check this is by using the observable approach I mentioned above and doing `{{ user$ | async | json }}` in your template to see what the call to `userService.get` is getting you.

Note that while you can get the manual subscription to work, you will need to handle clean up of the subscription yourself. The `async` pipe is the way to go for this type of thing.

For more information on that, check here: https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: I've done what you have mencioned but doesnt work, nothing appears in the browser, as if it was empty the response (and of course its not).

Answer (score 0):

First, You'll need to import Response from @angular/http into your service.

```
import { Http, Headers, Response } from "@angular/http";
```

And map from rx/js:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Then, in your service, try the following:

```
return this.http.get(this._url + id).pipe(
  map((resp:Response) => resp.json())
)
```

This should map your response to JSON. Subscribing to the observable should work the way you have it now in your component.

Comment: Can't use .json()  It says "the property 'json' doesnt exist for my interface IUser"

Comment: My bad... you should probably be using your interface on the mapped data that comes back (in the component). You're already declaring this.user as IUser, so removing <IUser> from your API call might work. I'll update my answer...

Comment: And how could I get the data then in the component? could you tell me aswell? Thanks